# Convert multi-line into one and extract columns from it

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have a stream(from propitiatory tool named mytool) of logs which are in xml format and I need to make them look readable in one line. I do not have xml parsing tool on this node , so ended up using perl and awk.

I managed to get the desired result but wanted to reduce the number of pipes/awk/perl into minimum possible.

Example of input stream:

```
./mytool

<ALERT>
   <Time>2018-10-24T16:03:00.128-05:00</Time>
   <Alert>0;2018-10-24T16:02:37.739-05:00;NODE_LOCATION=19;11193;ID=5636122;Temp is on critical range;000;CRITICAL;Recovery=Shutting down the node;100</Alert>
</ALERT>



<ALERT>
   <Time>2018-10-24T16:03:03.053-05:00</Time>
   <Alert>0;2018-10-24T16:02:40.264-05:00;NODE_LOCATION=17;11293;ID=5636124;Temp is on Major range;000;MAJOR;Recovery=Shutdown the node or it will auto shutdown,processes stopped;99</Alert>
</ALERT>
```

My desired result:

```
2018-10-24T16:02:37.739-05:00  5636122 Temp is on critical range CRITICAL Shutting down the node
2018-10-24T16:02:40.264-05:00  5636124 Temp is on Major range MAJOR Shutdown the node or it will auto shutdown,processes stopped
```

Current command I used to get the result:

```
./mytool | perl -000 -lnpe 's/<.*?>|NODE_LOCATION=|Recovery=|ID=//g' | awk -vRS= '{$1=$1}1' |awk -F';' '{print $2,$$4,$5,$6,$8,$9}'

2018-10-24T16:02:37.739-05:00  5636122 Temp is on critical range CRITICAL Shutting down the node
2018-10-24T16:02:40.264-05:00  5636124 Temp is on Major range MAJOR Shutdown the node or it will auto shutdown,processes stopped
```

Note: Understand that using awk perl is not the best way to deal with xmls but this is the best possible available so have to compromise with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(considering that your output of script will be always in same pattern as per shown output).

```
your_command | awk -F"[><]" '
/<Time>/{
  val=$3
  next
}
/<Alert>/{
  split($3,array,";")
  sub(/.*=/,"",array[5])
  sub(/Recovery=/,"",array[9])
  print val,array[5],array[6],array[8],array[9]
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mytool | perl -nE 'if(/<Alert>/){s/Recovery=|ID=//g; say join " ",(split/;/)[1,4,5,7,8]}'
```

The above will work assuming your XML only has one tag pair per line as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do all in Perl if you want. Avoiding pipes to `awk`. For example:

```
mytool | perl -nE '
  m{<Alert>(.*?)</Alert>} and do {($line = $1) =~ s/NODE_LOCATION=|Recovery=|ID=//g; 
  @F = split /;/, $line; say join " ", @F[1,3,4,5,6,7,8]}'
```